# Postfix exit code 75

Tags: apt

When I want to update or upgrade anything. or can install any kinks of software. The terminal shows this message "1 not fully install or remove". and installing process stops:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
**1 not fully installed or removed.**
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
```

Finally this error message is shown, and installing or updating process stops:

```
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 installed postfix package post-installation script subprocess returned error ex
it status 75
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.33-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Packages that are "not fully installed or removed" generally must be reinstalled.

`sudo apt install --reinstall <package_name>`

However, that won't work in your specific case, because [postfix exit code 75](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postfix/+question/173875) usually occurs when you have an invalid hostname.

It's not a dpkg or postfix problem; it's a hostname problem that has been exposed by your package actions.

How to change the hostname depends upon which release of Ubuntu you are running, and whether or not you are willing to reboot the system.